# Data outside requested BBOX

Tags: gis, kml, google-earth, arcgis

I am trying to convert a large layer map from ArcGIS into a KML file for Google Earth.  When I increase the DPI to 300 or even 500 and export my layer file to Google Earth it is still extremely blurry.  I thought a way around this would be to measure the map into 4 quadrants and then export each quadrant, however as soon as I adjust one of the extent properties the kml will no longer be displayed in google Earth.  The file can be seen in the Places tab on the left with a note saying "Data outside requested BBOX".  The layer is in WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_8N.  I am super confused because I can export the map as one large pixellated file but when I try to shrink the extent properties and export, there is no image in the kml file.  ArcGIS successfully completes the task of exporting the layer to kml, but the error is found in GoogleEarth when I open up the newly created kml file.

Answer (score 0):

so do this - instead of using the Layer to KML tool,  export the image to a georeferenced format (maybe GeoTIFF) and just drag the image into GE - it will create a "superoverlay" for you that will not be pixellated.